# Why Won't My Careers Profile Update My Location?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I moved, I've updated my location on my profile....and yet it still says that I live in the old place.

I'm getting really tired of hearing from recruiters for jobs where I don't live.

Comment: Did you update your location in your developer story too?

Comment: @animuson I believe the developer story location updates automatically in response to profile location changes.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Not if you turn synchronization off.

Comment: Also, [just ignore the do not reply thingy.](/questions/350303/please-reply-to-do-not-replystackoverflow-com)

Comment: @animuson i did update it there, i think first. i think its tied to my se profile, because i can see the old address here: https://stackexchange.com/users/173164/albert but when i go to update my profile it just asks me to pull my profile in from another SO site.

Comment: @albert Your stackexchange.com profile doesn't matter in relation to Jobs. Your *developer story* (click on the Developer Story tab on your Stack Overflow profile) does still have your old location on it. Hover over the top section of your story and the edit button will appear.

Comment: @animuson thank you so much! i was clicking on the edit button to the right. that's a little less than intuitive for me, but i certainly appreciate your help!

Comment: Did animuson's suggestion take care of it for you, @albert?

Comment: @JNat indeed it did!

Comment: @animuson if you would like to post your comment as an answer, it will be accepted